# Query python gdata Calendar API by extended properties

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gdata

Using the Python GData Calendar API, is there a way to search/query for events with specific extended properties?

Ie, my program is creating calendar events and setting an extended property ProgramID='xxxxx'. In a later period, I'd like to find all of the events where extended_property.ProgramID=='xxxx'

I'm currently accomplishing this by doing a general query and then looping through each looking for the correct extended properties. It's extremely time and CPU intensive, so I'd like to speed up the process.

```
    query = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarEventQuery()
    feed = gcal.GetCalendarEventFeed(q=query)
    for i, calEvent in enumerate(feed.entry):
        calEventProperties = calEvent.extended_property

    mikkiEvent = False
    mikkiEventKey = ''

    for eventProperty in  calEventProperties:

            if eventProperty.name == SETTINGS['CALID']:
        mikkiEvent = True

    if eventProperty.name == str(SETTINGS['CALID'] + 'EventKey'):
        mikkiEventKey = eventProperty.value
```

I can't find a place in the API Doc explaining how to add an extended property query to the query.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you can not query by extended properties.

Depending on how much control you have over the application and the calendars you can work around this by placing some sort of meta-data on the description field, querying for that and then filtering the results (as you're currently doing) via the extended property match.